# "RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0" PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I've been trying to build a simple neural network with linear layers:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(64 * 1 * 28 * 28, 6)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(6, 4)
        self.out = nn.Linear(4, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.shape)
        
        x = self.lin1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        
        x = self.lin2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        
        x = self.out(x)
        x = F.softmax(x)
        
        return x
```

However I run into the error:

> mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0

for the line

```
x = self.lin1(x)
```

I tried flattening `x` before `lin1` or changing the `lin1` input size, but nothing worked.

The output of the print statement is:

```
torch.Size([64, 1, 28, 28])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by flattening (in a different way than i did before) the input.

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Net,self).__init__()
    
    self.lin1 = nn.Linear(784,6)
    self.lin2  = nn.Linear(6,4)
    self.out = nn.Linear(4,10)
   

def forward(self,x):
    
    x = torch.flatten(x,start_dim = 1) #This is new
    
    x = self.lin1(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    
    x = self.lin2(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    
    x = self.out(x)
    
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

An input to `nn.Linear(a, b)` must be of the shape `torch.Size([N, a])`. So in your case you'd need to reshape `x` to e.g. `x.reshape(64, -1)`

Comment: I tried putting `x = x.reshape(64,-1)` before lin1, but im still receiving the same error. Also changed the layer to `nn.Linear(64,6)` and even then received the error.

Comment: Can you then please post an [MCVE], otherwise it is not possible to reproduce your error.

Comment: Okay i solved it by just setting the linearLayer to `nn.Linear(28,6)` -> last dim of the tensor.

Comment: Note that this does something completely different! I assume you're trying to create an MNIST (or similar) classifier, so this would mean you train a classifier on the *columns* of your picture, that is, you get a classification for each column, and this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yea im trying to classify the MNIST set with a softmax. Im still having a bit of trouble understanding what each number in the Tensore means. When reshape to `(64,-1)` the output shape is: `torch.Size([64, 784])`, should i just put the linear layer input to 784 then?

Comment: Yes exactly.  For `torch.nn.Linear` all except the last dimension are considered as "batch". So if you have an input tensor of size `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` you basically have to consider it as an  `3 x 4 x 5 x 6 x 7`-array of vectors of size `8` to put in to `nn.Linear`. Usually for `nn.Linear` you only use 2d-arrays (that is e.g. of shape `[10, 8]` where `10` is your batch size).

Comment: That seems to be working so far, thanks! However the last batch size for the last minibatch is of size `392`, which then throws thed dim-error again. How do i handle this case?

Comment: Can you clarify, what exactly is the shape of the input now?

Comment: The input of the last minibatch is `torch.Size([64, 392])`

Comment: This means the batch size is `64`, and the dimension of your data now is `392`, but it seems `392` does not macht the input size of `nn.Linear`. Compare again to my answer.